# Perl program to mimic restriction enzymes using references, hash tables and subs

Tags: regex, perl, hash, reference, bioinformatics

I'm a student in an intro Perl class. I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach an assignment. My professor encourages forums. The assignment is:

> Write a Perl program that will take two files from the command line, an enzyme file and a DNA file. Read the file with restriction enzymes and apply the restriction enzymes to the DNA file.
>
> The output will be fragments of DNA arranged in the order they occur in the dna file. The name of the output files should be constructed by appending the name of the restriction enzyme to the name of the DNA file, with an underscore between them.
>
> For example, if the enzyme is EcoRI and the DNA file is named BC161026, the output file should be named BC161026_EcoRI.

My approach is to create a main program and two subs as follows:

Main:
   Not sure how to tie my subs together?

Sub program $DNA:
    Take a DNA file and remove any new lines to make a single string

Sub program Enzymes:
    Read and store the lines from the enzyme file which is from the command line
    Parse the file in a way that it separates the enzyme acronym from the position of the cut. 
    Store the position of the cut as a regular expression in a hash table 
    Store the name of the acronym in a hash table

> Note on enzyme file format:
>   The enzyme file follows a format known as Staden. Examples:
>
> `AatI/AGG'CCT//`
>      `AatII/GACGT'C//`
>      `AbsI/CC'TCGAGG//`
>
> The enzyme acronym consists of the characters before the first slash (AatI, in the first example. The recognition sequence is everything between the first and second slash (AGG'CCT, again, in the first example). The cut point is denoted by an apostrophe in the recognition sequence
>   There are standard abbreviations for dna within enzymes as follows:
>
> R = G or A
>      B = not A (C or G or T)
>      etc...

Along with a recommendation for a main chunk, do you see any missing pieces that I've omitted? Can you recommend specific tools that you think would be useful in patching this program together?

Example input enzyme: `TryII/RRR'TTT//`

Example string to read: `CCCCCCGGGTTTCCCCCCCCCCCCAAATTTCCCCCCCCCCCCAGATTTCCCCCCCCCCGAGTTTCCCCC`

The output should be:

> CCCCCCGGG
>
> TTTCCCCCCCCCCCCAAA
>
> TTTCCCCCCCCCCCCAGA
>
> TTTCCCCCCCCCCGAG
>
> TTTCCCCC

Comment: You may want to try asking this question on BioStar http://biostar.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Those are not backslashes.  This is a backslash: \  This is a forward slash (or just "slash"): /

Comment: I know the difference between backslash and slash it was an oversight but thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks gotgenes! I didn't know of Biostar. Looks awesome and I will definitely explore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I know I shouldn't just do your homework, but there were some fun tricks to this one, so I played with it. Learn from this, not just copy. I didn't comment very well, so if there is something you don't understand, please ask. There is some slight magic in this that if you haven't covered it in your class, your prof will know, so be sure you understand.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my ($enzyme_file, $dna_file);
my $write_output = 0;
my $verbose = 0;
my $help = 0;
GetOptions(
  'enzyme=s' => \$enzyme_file,
  'dna=s' => \$dna_file,
  'output' => \$write_output,
  'verbose' => \$verbose,
  'help' => \$help
);

$help = 1 unless ($dna_file && $enzyme_file);
help() if $help; # exits

# 'Main'
my $dna = getDNA($dna_file);
my %enzymes = %{ getEnzymes($enzyme_file) }; # A function cannot return a hash, so return a hashref and then store the referenced hash
foreach my $enzyme (keys %enzymes) {
  print "Applying enzyme " . $enzyme . " gives:\n";
  my $dna_holder = $dna;
  my ($precut, $postcut) = ($enzymes{$enzyme}{'precut'}, $enzymes{$enzyme}{'postcut'});

  my $R = qr/[GA]/;
  my $B = qr/[CGT]/;

  $precut =~ s/R/${R}/g;
  $precut =~ s/B/${B}/g;
  $postcut =~ s/R/${R}/g;
  $postcut =~ s/B/${B}/g;
  print "\tPre-Cut pattern: " . $precut . "\n" if $verbose;
  print "\tPost-Cut pattern: " . $postcut . "\n" if $verbose;

  #while(1){
  #  if ($dna_holder =~ s/(.*${precut})(${postcut}.*)/$1/ ) {
  #    print "\tFound section:" . $2 . "\n" if $verbose;
  #    print "\tRemaining DNA: " . $1 . "\n" if $verbose;
  #    unshift @{ $enzymes{$enzyme}{'cut_dna'} }, $2;
  #  } else {
  #    unshift @{ $enzymes{$enzyme}{'cut_dna'} }, $dna_holder;
  #    print "\tNo more cuts.\n" if $verbose;
  #    print "\t" . $_ . "\n" for @{ $enzymes{$enzyme}{'cut_dna'} };
  #    last;
  #  }
  #}
  unless ($dna_holder =~ s/(${precut})(${postcut})/$1'$2/g) {
    print "\tHas no effect on given strand\n" if $verbose;
  }
  @{ $enzymes{$enzyme}{'cut_dna'} } = split(/'/, $dna_holder);
  print "\t$_\n" for @{ $enzymes{$enzyme}{'cut_dna'} };

  writeOutput($dna_file, $enzyme, $enzymes{$enzyme}{'cut_dna'}) if $write_output; #Note that $enzymes{$enzyme}{'cut_dna'} is an arrayref already
  print "\n";
}

sub getDNA {
  my ($dna_file) = @_;

  open(my $dna_handle, '<', $dna_file) or die "Cannot open file $dna_file";
  my @dna_array = <$dna_handle>;
  chomp(@dna_array);

  my $dna = join('', @dna_array);

  print "Using DNA:\n" . $dna . "\n\n" if $verbose;
  return $dna;
}

sub getEnzymes {
  my ($enzyme_file) = @_;
  my %enzymes;

  open(my $enzyme_handle, '<', $enzyme_file) or die "Cannot open file $enzyme_file";
  while(<$enzyme_handle>) {
    chomp;
    if(m{([^/]*)/([^']*)'([^/]*)//}) {
      print "Found Enzyme " . $1 . ":\n\tPre-cut: " . $2 . "\n\tPost-cut: " . $3 . "\n" if $verbose;
      $enzymes{$1} = {
        precut => $2,
        postcut => $3,
        cut_dna => [] #Added to show the empty array that will hold the cut DNA sections
      };
    }
  }

  print "\n" if $verbose;
  return \%enzymes;
}

sub writeOutput {

  my ($dna_file, $enzyme, $cut_dna_ref) = @_;

  my $outfile = $dna_file . '_' . $enzyme;
  print "\tSaving data to $outfile\n" if $verbose; 
  open(my $outfile_handle, '>', $outfile) or die "Cannot open $outfile for writing";

  print $outfile_handle $_ . "\n" for @{ $cut_dna_ref };
}

sub help {

  my $filename = (split('/', $0))[-1];

  my $enzyme_text = <<'END';
AatI/AGG'CCT//
AatII/GACGT'C//
AbsI/CC'TCGAGG//
TryII/RRR'TTT//
Test/AAA'TTT//
END

  my $dna_text = <<'END';
CCCCCCGGGTTTCCCCCCC
CCCCCAAATTTCCCCCCCCCCCCAGATTTC
CCCCCCCCCGAGTTTCCCCC
END

  print <<END;
Usage: 
    $filename --enzyme (-e) <enzyme-filename> --dna (-d) <dna-filename> [options] (files may come in either order)
    $filename -h    (shows this help)

Options: 
    --verbose (-v)  print additional (debugging) information
    --output (-o)   output final data to files


Files:
The DNA file contains one DNA string which may be broken over many lines. E.G.:

$dna_text

The enzymes file constains enzyme definitions, one per line. E.G.:

$enzyme_text
END

exit;
}
```

Edit: Added cut_dna initialization explicitly because this is the final result holder for each enzyme, so I thought it would be good to see it more clearly.

Edit 2: Added output routine, call, flag and corresponding help.

Edit 3: Changed main routine to incorporate the best of canavanin's method while removing loops. Now its a global replace to add temporary cut mark (') and then split on cut mark into array. Left old method as comment, new method is the 5 lines following.

Edit 4: Additional test case for writing to multiple files. (Below)

```
my @names = ('cat','dog','sheep'); 
foreach my $name (@names) { #$name is lexical, ie dies after each loop
  open(my $handle, '>', $name); #open a lexical handle for the file, also dies each loop
  print $handle $name; #write to the handle
  #$handles closes automatically when it "goes out of scope"
}
```

Comment: Also this doesn't do the output file, just writes to STDOUT. Certainly getting the file into the proper format is something you should be able to do :-)

Comment: Thanks Joel! Your solution is over my head but gives me a high bar to reach to. It has also given me some ideas to begin trying. Can you tell me more about the Verbose element you wrote in?

Comment: `$verbose` is a global flag, if set to true (1), then it prints more than just the results, more like debugging info. Notice the `print ... if $verbose`, this it the postfix conditional way of printing only if a condition is true.

Comment: Thanks for the recent edit to your code in making the result holder clearer. I know you credit me with being able to get the file into the proper format but I'm afraid I've been working on it for a while with no luck. I've tried creating another sub for output and referencing it in the main but my attempt is garbage. Can you give me a hint of where you would write in the Output specifics? Thanks again for the feedback here and in other answers.

Comment: Sorry for the bad syntax highlighting after edit 3. SO doesn't highlight Perl very well. If the split mark weren't the single quote (') it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Any idea how to make a new output file for each enzyme? Right now they're overwriting each other.

Comment: When I run my code it works. Does your writing routine define a new file name each time for the open command? Perhaps I should ask, you end up with only one file, what name does it have?

Comment: I should ask too, do you know how to use the perl documentation, `perldoc -f open` and `perldoc -f print` would help you here. Then `perldoc perlintro` is a great way to get familiar with other Perl-ish ways. Also if I have a problem with some facet of a program, it is often best to isolate it in a simple test case program, like I added above.

Comment: Joel - I got it, thanks a million. I've learned a ton from your direction and code - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Note that in Enzymes, when you store an enzyme in the hash the name of the enzyme should be the key and the site should be the value (since in principle two enzymes could have identical sites).

In the Main routine, you can iterate through the hash; for each enzyme produce one output file. The most direct way is to translate the site to a regex (by means of other regexs) and apply it to the DNA sequence, but there are other ways. (It is probably worth splitting this off into at least one other sub.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I have gone about trying to solve the problem (code below). 

1) The file names are picked up from the arguments and respective `filehandles` are created.
2) A new file handle is created for the output file which in the specified format
3) The "cut points" are extracted from the first file
4) The DNA Sequences in the second file are looped over the cut points obtained in step **3**.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file_enzyme=$ARGV[0];
my $file_dna=$ARGV[1];

open DNASEQ, ">$file_dna"."_"."$file_enzyme";
open ENZYME, "$file_enzyme";
open DNA, "$file_dna";
while (<ENZYME>) {
 chomp;
  if( /'(.*)\/\//) { # Extracts the cut point between ' & // in the enzyme file
    my $pattern=$1;
    while (<DNA>) {
     chomp;
     #print $pattern;
     my @output=split/$pattern/,;
     print DNASEQ shift @output,"\n"; #first recognized sequence being output
     foreach (@output) {
        print DNASEQ "$pattern$_\n"; #prefixing the remaining sequences with the cut point pattern
     }
   }
 }
}
close DNA;
close ENZYME;
close DNASEQ;
```

Comment: use warnings; even more important than use strict.

Comment: Have added `use warnings` as per your recommendation however snippet was merely of-the-cuff to address Koala's problem. Thanks nonetheless

Comment: Thanks philar, I've worked in many aspects of this program that you suggest and they seem to be working great! I have a little more to work out in creating a hash for the pre and post cut symbols of the enzymes and using those acronyms as files for the output. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't mention it, kinda brushed up on my high school biology along the way:)

Comment: Without doing explicit testing, it seems like this will incorrectly cut at any point that has the post-cut match, even if it doesn't have the pre-cut match. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I don't see it.

Comment: This also doesn't handle linefeeds (newlines) in the dna file correctly. @philar, sorry, not trying to be difficult.

Comment: @Joel that's fine. Could you clarify what you mean by not handling new lines? In my bid to whip up the code, I did miss inserting the pre and post cut symbols in a hash. However did test it against the example given by the OP. Will appreciate it if you could give another test case which would allow me to see the fallacies that you've mentioned. Cheers mate

Comment: "Sub program $DNA: Take a DNA file and remove any new lines to make a single string". Your while(<DNA>) would miss a cut that was spread over two lines is all. I'm sure you know how to do this, just that you missed it in the post.

Comment: If the DNA was in the file as CCCCCCGG\nGTTTCCCCCCCCCCCCAAATTTCCCCCCCCCCCCAGATTTCCCCCCCCCCGAGTTTCCCCC you would miss the first cut

Comment: And would incorrectly cut ...IIICCC... (pseudoDNA: I=incorrect, C=Correct) for any enzyme (Name/CCC'CCC//).

Answer (score 2):

I know there have been several answers already, but hey... I just felt like trying my luck, so here's my suggestion:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($enz_file, $dna_file);

GetOptions( "e=s" => \$enz_file,
            "d=s" => \$dna_file,
          );

if (! $enz_file || ! $dna_file) {
   # some help text 
   print STDERR<<EOF; 

   Usage: restriction.pl -e enzyme_file -d DNA_file

   The enzyme_file should contain one enzyme entry per line.
   The DNA_file may contain the sequence on one single or on
   several lines; all lines will be concatenated to yield a
   single string.
EOF      
   exit();
}

my %enz_and_patterns; # stores enzyme name and corresponding pattern

open ENZ, "<$enz_file" or die "Could not open file $enz_file: $!";
while (<ENZ>) {
   if (m#^(\w+)/([\w']+)//$#) {
      my $enzyme  = $1; # could also remove those two lines and use 
      my $pattern = $2; # the match variables directly, but this is clearer

      $enz_and_patterns{$enzyme} = $pattern;
   }
}
close ENZ;

my $dna_sequence;

open DNA, "<$dna_file" or die "Could not open file $dna_file: $!";
while (my $line = <DNA>) {
   chomp $line;
   $dna_sequence .= $line; # append the current bit to the sequence
                           # that has been read so far
}
close DNA;

foreach my $enzyme (keys %enz_and_patterns) {
   my $dna_seq_processed = $dna_sequence; # local copy so that we retain the original

   # now translate the restriction pattern to a regular expression pattern:
   my $pattern = $enz_and_patterns{$enzyme};
   $pattern    =~ s/R/[GA]/g; # use character classes
   $pattern    =~ s/B/[^A]/g;
   $pattern    =~ s/(.+)'(.+)/($1)($2)/; # remove the ', but due to the grouping
                                         # we "remember" its position

   $dna_seq_processed =~ s/$pattern/$1\n$2/g; # in effect we are simply replacing
                                              # each ' with a newline character
   my $outfile = "${dna_file}_$enzyme";
   open OUT, ">$outfile" or die "Could not open file $outfile: $!";
   print OUT $dna_seq_processed , "\n";
   close OUT;
}
```

I've tested my code with your TryII example, which worked fine.

As this is a task which can be handled by writing just a few lines of non-repetitive code I didn't feel creating separate subroutines would have been justified. I hope I will be forgiven... :)

Comment: @canavanin I just saw your answer now. This is a great solution, thanks! The program is not acknowledging the initializing of my $enzyme = $1 and my $pattern =$2 for the open ENZ block, any ideas why?

Comment: @Koala Sorry, I don't quite get the problem you're having. Could you please elaborate on it a bit? Thanks :)

Comment: Personally think its less flexible, but creative. The variables are only being used to populate the hash %enz_and_patterns, then they "go out of scope", that is to say cease to exist.

Comment: @Joel What is it that makes you think my solution not that flexible? (not trying to be offensive, I just like to get code-improving suggestions from time to time)

Comment: @canavanin when I incorporate the block that "open ENZ" followed by "<$enz_file" or die " The return message is "uninitialized value $enz_file in cancatenation ..." I've tried to initialize my $enz_file and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Koala Are you running my entire program or have you (it sounds like this) copied a portion to a program of your own?

Comment: @Koala Your $enz_file doesn't seem to hold any file name. I will now add a usage instruction to my code (see above), perhaps that will help to clarify things a bit.

Comment: Thank you canavanin I was running a portion of the program to my own and I think that was the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @canavanin the only thing I would say is that while your method makes a change to the information as stored, mine extracts it and separates into a data structure. This would mean that if the output format needed would change, mine would only take a small amount of change to the output routine, where yours would have to re-parse the information that has already been examined. Not a big issue, plus your replace ' with \n was very clever method.

Comment: @canavanin, updated my method to include the gist of yours, nice working with you :-)

Comment: @Joel Nice to see someone use something I came up with ^^